# Updating entities with primary key and alternate composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a series of metric snapshot data I am uploading into my database on a daily basis. I take the input and check to determine if it is already in the database, and if it's not I add it. Each record uses a composite key made up of three columns, and also has a primary key.

I have since tried to add logic so that I can optionally force an update on records that already exist in the database, in addition to adding those that don't yet exist. I run into an error though preventing me, saying that there is already an object with the specified key being tracked.

> The instance of entity type 'MembershipSnapshot' cannot be tracked
>   because another instance of this type with the same key is already
>   being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique
>   temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key
>   property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are
>   explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not
>   collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other
>   new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
>   entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

Here's a snippet of my code.

```
    // Get the composite keys from the supplied list
    var snapshotKeys = snapshots.Select(s => new { s.MembershipYear, s.DataDate, s.Aggregate }).ToArray();
    // Find which records already exist in the database, pulling their composite keys
    var snapshotsInDb = platformContext.MembershipSnapshots.Where(s => snapshotKeys.Contains(new { s.MembershipYear, s.DataDate, s.Aggregate }))
                                       .Select(s => new { s.MembershipYear, s.DataDate, s.Aggregate }).ToArray();
    // And filter them out, so we remain with the ones that don't yet exist
    var addSnapshots = snapshots.Where(s => !snapshotsInDb.Contains(new { s.MembershipYear, s.DataDate, s.Aggregate }))
        .ToList();
    // Update the ones that already exist
    var updateSnapshots = snapshots.Where(s => snapshotsInDb.Contains(new { s.MembershipYear, s.DataDate, s.Aggregate }))
        .ToList();
    platformContext.MembershipSnapshots.AddRange(addSnapshots);
    platformContext.MembershipSnapshots.UpdateRange(updateSnapshots);
    platformContext.SaveChanges();
```

How do I go about accomplishing this task?

I don't have a compelling reason why I have an auto-increment primary key, other than perhaps whatever performance issues it might give SQL internally?

EDIT: The way I've currently solved this issue is my removing my surrogate key, which I'm not using at all for anything. Still, it would be nice to know a workaround without having to remove this as a surrogate key could come in handy in the future.

Comment: Is the data in `snapshots` being pulled from the database?

Comment: @Brad No, they are being retrieved from a file. And one might also think snapshots are immutable, but unfortunately in my case they're not.

Comment: Do the snapshots that you retrieve from a file contain the right value of the surrogate key when they already exist in the database? If they don't, e.g. if they contained a default value such as zero, by the time you call UpdateRange() you are basically telling EF Core that there are multiple entities that exist in the database and have the same key value of zero, which is not valid.

Comment: @divega I understand, and that's where the problem lies. When I'm dealing with a single object, it'll just grab the key for me when I tell it the object already exists and is only being modified... but I guess you just cannot do that with a range?

Comment: The issue is what data EF Core can use to identify which rows in the database needs to be updated. If you don't have a surrogate key then the data in the object is enough. But if you do use a surrogate key you need the value of the key to be set before you call Update() or UpdateRange() (whether you are dealing with a single object or multiple objects shouldn't matter). Now, you can have the right value for the surrogate key in the file, or you can perform another preparation step that copies the key values from the database rows to the objects you will be updating.

Comment: So my solution was best then... remove the surrogate key, and change the composite key to be primary since the system that generates the file with the snapshots doesn't know the surrogate key... it's an external data warehouse.